# Re-format MySQL DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I wanted to re-format mysql DateTime data type from **2011-12-08 08:31:23** to **Dec 8, 2011 8:31 am** while displaying on browser using PHP5 so I used

```
$create_date=date("M j, Y g:i a", strtotime($f["create_date"]));
```

and it is live on godaddy server but it is showing morning entries to **pm** and evening entries to to **am**..?

Comment: @eureka: I guess the OP wants them to be the correct way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time difference between Arizona and Pakistan is 12 hours. `strtotime` uses godaddy's server time when converting to a Unix timestamp.

Use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set your time zone.